# $\wedge$-product, alternating

Tags: multilinear-algebra

I want to show, that the $\wedge$-product of multilinear forms is alternating. Therefore

$\omega\wedge\eta(\dotso, v,\dotso, v,\dotso)=0$

Since $\omega$ and $\eta$ are already alternating multilinear forms, there is only one interesting case. 
The case

$\frac{1}{r!s!}\sum_{\tau\in S_{r+s}} sgn(\tau)\omega(v_{\tau(1)},\dotso,v,\dotso,v_{\tau(r)})\eta(v_{\tau(r+1)},\dotso,v,\dotso,v_{\tau(r+s)})\stackrel{?}{=}0$

I do not see, how to get this result.
Is there an easy way, or is it an exhausting calculation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's easy. For each such $\tau$, consider the permutation $\tau'$ that is identical to $\tau$ except that it switches the positions of those two $v$, The summand given by $\tau'$ cancels out the summand given by $\tau$, since it has a different sign. So the summands simply cancel out pairwise.

Comment: Thank you! That makes everything clear.