# Wedge product of alternating forms is again alternating – Definition with shufles

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let $V$ be a $k$-vector space ($k$ a field of arbitrary characteristic, or even just a commutative ring) and let $\alpha \colon V^r \to k$ and $\beta \colon V^s \to k$ be alternating multilinear forms on $V$. Define the wedge product $\alpha \wedge \beta \colon V^{r+s} \to k$ via the formula
$$(\alpha \wedge \beta)(v_1, \dots, v_{r+s}) = \sum_{\sigma \in \mathrm{Sh}(r,s)} \mathrm{sign}(\sigma) \alpha(v_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, v_{\sigma(r)})\beta(v_{\sigma(r+1)}, \dots, v_{\sigma(r+s)}),$$
where $\mathrm{Sh(r,s)}$ denotes the set of *shuffles* where a shuffle is a permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1, \dots, r+s\}$ such that $\sigma(1) < \dots < \sigma(r)$ and $\sigma(r+1) < \dots < \sigma(r+s)$. This definition is given for example in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Alternating_multilinear_forms).

I have a hard time showing that $\alpha \wedge \beta$ is again alternating. I cannot manage to modify the proof given for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922096/wedge-product-alternating) in a comment, where the sum is taken over all permutations of $\{1, \dots, s\}$ (which turns out to be equivalent in fields of characteristic $0$).

Comment: You need to show that whenever $v_1 = v_2$, then $(\alpha \wedge \beta)(v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_{r + s}) = 0$. For shuffles where $v_1$ and $v_2$ both land in $\alpha$ on the right hand side, clearly we get 0 for that term in the sum since $\alpha$ is alternating. Similarly for $\beta$. That leaves those shuffles where $v_1$ lands in $\alpha$ and $v_2$ lands in $\beta$, where you will have to count shuffles and ensure that the signs make them cancel to 0.